# extjs How to get a grid

Tags: variables, extjs, grid

In Designer I set my grid name to equal MyGrid

On clicking the button addRecord is called, it fails where rows is attemting to get an undefined grid.

How do I define this MyGrid so that it references the grid within the panel?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.MyPanel',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        var button = me.down('button[text=Submit]');

         button.on('click', me.onSubmitBtnClick, me);
    },

    addRecord: function(myRecordArray) {

        var rows = grid.getStore().getRange(); // ERROR happens here

            console.log(rows);


    },

    onSubmitBtnClick: function() {
        this.addRecord(["ll", "kk", "mm"]);
    }
});
```

Chrome Javascript Debugger Console ->

```
   Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before you call `grid.getStore()` you need to define "grid". You can just do `var grid = this;` right before the call because you are defining the addRecord function from inside of the grid.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that this wasn't being called from inside the grid panel with the store but some other panel. What you will have to do to is set an id config on your grid panel. E.g. `id: MyGridPanel` There may already be an id config set on it and you just have to find out what it is. If you are using the ExtJS designer it *may* actually already be set to "MyGridPanel". Then you would call it like so:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp("MyGridPanel");
```

*then* you would do:

```
grid.getStore().getRange()
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `button.on('click', me.onSubmitBtnClick, me)` to `button.on('click', Ext.bind(me.onSubmitBtnClick, me), me)`

This looks like a scope issue, in your `onSubmitBtn()` method, `this` probably refering to the wrong object (e.g. window, or the button), and not the grid object, which is what you want.

Comment: made the edit but it is working and failing just the same.  I do not believe it is an error with the button, just wanted to show the idea of an event.

Comment: Chrome Javascript Debugger Console -> Uncaught ReferenceError: grid is not defined

Comment: I also see you extend MyApp.view.ui.MyPanel? does that extend GridPanel? Probably should just put debugger statement before the this.addRecord in onSubmitBtnClick, just to see what this refers to, and Apart from that I don't have any other suggestions - Sorry its been a long time since I did any ExtJS work.

Comment: it refers to -> Ext.Class.newClass